# Op-amp Forward biased or negative biased?

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwTAu7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I came across this question and just want to know whether my answer to this question is logically right.
The question is- Is the opamp forward or reverse biased. Also tell the value of V?
Now using Circuit Lab simulation I know it is reverse biased and the value of V. Now logically solving the question-
If I increase the value of V+, the output of opamp V will increase. This increase in V will cause the value of Ve to increase and hence the emitter current of BJT will increase and thus the collector current. This increase in collector current will bring down the value of V+ and hence we get a stable output and thus it is reverse biased.
Now is my reasoning right or am I going somewhere wrong here?

Comment: Your analysis is correct.

Comment: Did you work out the value of _V_ yet?

Comment: @transistor V=2v, assuming Vbe=0.7v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transistor Q1 along with R1 and R2 form an inverting amplifier, that acts as a buffer for the operational amplifier.

Since we add an inverting stage the inputs (+ and -) of the opamp are effectively reversed and the '+' input now has to be used for negative feedback. The output at the collector of Q1 is now the output of the buffered opamp.

It is now easy to see that the whole circuit is in a negative feedback configuration or a follower configuration to be more precise.

Comment: Please clarify the points- 1) You say it is inverting because it is in CE configuration? 2)How does the transistor act as a buffer? When the opamp is in negative feedback- V=2v and V+=5v. The input and output are not the same. So how is it a Buffer.

Comment: @Rachit Jain -- 1) Yes 2) In this context the term buffer does not imply that the input and the output are the same. For example emitter followers are often used as a buffer, but input and ouput are not the same (though the output tracks the input). However, the main point was that the stage is inverting.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unusual in that (in my experience) we don't normally talk of "bias" in relation to op-amps in this way. Usuall a bias or reference is applied to one input or the other to achieve a certain effect or provide a reference voltage, for example.

The circuit is also interesting and unusual in that the feedback is applied to the non-inverting input. This is most often seen in Schmitt trigger circuits which are non-linear. Feedback is usually negative and is most commonly fed back to the inverting input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJFUqk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Schematic redrawn with conventional left to right flow and right to left feedback.*

My thought process when analysing the circuit runs as follows:

- The inverting input voltage is fixed at +5 V.
- Assume at power-on that Q1 is off. Therefore *V+* is pulled to +10 V by R2.
- Since the non-inverting input voltage is higher than the inverting input the output will swing towards the positive supply rail.
- Q1 will turn on causing current to flow through R2, Q1 and R1. *V+* will fall.
- If *V+* were to fall below the inverting voltage then OA1's output would swing towards the negative rail, shutting off Q1 and causing *V+* to rise again. It should settle down when *V+* is at +5 V.

Now the question is, "Can stability be achieved?" i.e., Will the component values allow *V+* to fall to +5 V?

> Now is my reasoning right or am I going somewhere wrong here?

Your reasoning is correct but if by "reverse biased" you mean *IN-* > *IN+* then not quite. With negative feedback the circuit should settle down at *IN-* = *IN+*.

Answer (score 0):

Bias is not a term that is used to describe this situation. The Op-amp is either stable (because of overall negative feedback) or unstable due to the extra gain of the BJT circuit (11 dB extra gain or 5k/1.4k).

This diagram is taken from the TL081 data sheet and tells you many things about stability when you close the loop on an op-amp: -

[image]

At a phase angle of 0 degrees (small red circle) the bode plot indicates that the op-amp has a gain of about -7 dB i.e. it is stable because there is less-than-unity gain when the phase has dropped to 0 dB. Adding 11 dB of gain is highly likely to make this little circuit turn into an oscillator with the average DC voltage on the collector being 5V.